# Eclipse RCP test run ok but the exported product was unable to open: Application could not be found in the registry

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a 3.x eclipse RCP product, when I click the `Lauch as an eclipse application` link at the overview tab of my product file, it went well. But when I export the product, the exe file cannot open, and the log is as follows, where **xx** is my application name.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2023-10-06 19:11:32.055
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "**xx**" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

I followed this tutorial https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html#deployment-of-your-application. Accordingly, the solution to a similar problem(Application ID could not be found) is that I should change the start level of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` to 1. I did so, but then the log information turned into something about the 3.15 version of `org.eclipse.equinox.common` requirement cannot be satisfied, so the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` cannot be resolved. So I guess this solution to my original question is inappropriate. How can I fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: There are usually five entries in the Start Levels - use the "Add Recommended" button on Configuration tab of the .product file editor to set the correct levels.

Comment: I did that. And the not found in registry error happened.

Comment: Experience shows that diagnosing this sort of problem in a question here is extremely difficult since it really requires looking at the entire setup of the RCP. Check that the product file is including all of your plug-ins and all the dependencies. Ideally use [tag:tycho] to do the product export as that is now the recommended method and may give better messages about issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a new product definition by clicking the new button in product donfiguration file, and I chose org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench as the application of that product definition. And then I changed the product to plugin-based, and added all the plugins. Then it worked.